# Dealing with js localized date in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, angular-material

My app (back-end in C# & front-end in Angular Materials) has a search screen allowing user to specify the date period using datepickers. The problem is that some of the users are not in UK while all the data they view has been created with GMT date. So if someone in Germany selects date 01/01/2017 in datepicker, my back-end reads it as 31/12/2016 23:00:00 resulting in incorrect search results. 
Can someone advise me how to deal with this? I'd like to still use the Angular Material datepicker but be sure that I'm passing the date selected by the user. I know I can transform the date before posting it like this:
`moment(myDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY'))`
but I have a lot of cases like this and would prefer some generic solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For transmission and storage, I advise using UTC for everything. Only at the point of display should the time be converted to whatever locale the user has selected. Despite this being an old problem, running into time conversion issues is still quite common. Most places I've worked at will store everything as UTC timestamps or Unix epoch time with respect to UTC, that way there is no question what the meaning is anywhere in the system. If/when it needs to be rendered to something local, we do it on the client side.

For example, to get the local time converted to UTC as a string:

```
var noTimeZone = new Date().toUTCString();
```

-or-

```
var noTimeZone = new Date().toISOString();
```

Or, if you want a numeric value so you don't have to deal with funky format parsing between client/server, you can get the Unix epoch:

```
var unixEpochMS = new Date().getTime();
```

Mind you, Date.getTime() will return **milliseconds** rather than seconds. Also note that the Unix epoch is defined in terms of UTC. That is, any numeric value that is a timestamp is expected to be UTC. If you want a different timezone, you need to parse the value and then set the timezone to what you want.

Comment: My code is querying old legacy system so I can't change the way dates are saved. They are all like this: 2013-01-26 11:32:33.070.

Comment: If I understand your post correctly, all the data is stored in GMT times. If that's the case, simply get the time entered by the user as UTC in javascript. For the purposes of solving your problem, GMT and UTC are synonymous.

Comment: Yes, that's correct and that's the solution I mentioned above. After a few tests today it looks like it's the only way to deal with it. Unless there is a way  I don't know off to force the javascript to ignore the timezone and always create UTC/GMT date when using Date object.

Comment: @johnblack I expanded my response to give you some more ideas on what to do. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**
I think the solution is to get your user's timezone. You can use Javascript to get timezone from user's computer and send it to server with the request.

```
var d = new Date();
var tz = d.getTimezoneOffset()/-60;
```

`tz` will be `2` if user's timezone is GM+2

**Soution 2:**
You send and receive Unix timestamp. But then you need to convert the timestamp to readable date/time based on user's timezone.

Comment: As I mentioned above, I already have the ad-hoc solution as I can pass the date as a formatted string by using moment(myDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY'). This way when user selects the date e.g. Sat Oct 01 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Summer Time) on the back-end I'll still have the correct date 10/01/2016 but I'm looking for some generic solution.